# What is UITableViewWrapperView?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview

I am trying to find out how to deal with an UITableViewWrapperView.

I can find no proper documentation on it.

I am guessing it is Likely to be a child of an UITableView.

I am trying to list the contents of the table, but I am only seeing the 6 or 7 in the current scroll view.

This is my code:

```
    public void Count_Forms()
    {
        string path="/mobileapp[@title='com.365agile.enterprise.365Agile-TEST']/form/container[@caption='' and @containertype='LayoutContainer']/container/container/container/container/container/container/table/container[1]";
        Common.IOS_Common_Functions.DumpProperties("UITableViewWrapperView2",path);
        Report.Info("Counting forms.");
        if(Common.RepoItemInfo.Wait_For_Control(
            repo.IOS365Agile.Com365agileEnterprise365AgileTEST.LayoutContainer.UITableViewWrapperView2Info,
            5000,string.Empty,false,string.Empty))
        {
            Ranorex.Container container=repo.IOS365Agile.Com365agileEnterprise365AgileTEST.LayoutContainer.UITableViewWrapperView2;
            int count=container.Children.Count ;
            Report.Info("Container has "+count .ToString ()+" children.");
            if(count>0)
            {
                IList<Ranorex.IosElement> elementList=container.FindChildren<Ranorex.IosElement>();                 
                foreach (var myElement in elementList )
                {
                    IList<Ranorex.IosElement> elementList2=myElement.FindChildren<Ranorex.IosElement>();  
                    foreach (var myElement2 in elementList2 )
                    {
                        // look for this:
                        // {Cell:A form created & edited using Ranorex Studio..+Created: 01/12/2015 11:45+Version: 4+Test Form #635845670192988975} 
                        if(myElement2.ToString().Contains("{Cell"))
                        {
                            string elementString=myElement2.ToString();
                            string mySubString = elementString.Substring(elementString.Length-30); // Form name is last 30 characters of text.
                            mySubString = mySubString.Remove(mySubString.Length-1); // chop off last character
                            Report.Info("mySubString+"+mySubString);
                        }
//                      IList<Ranorex.IosElement> elementList3=myElement2.FindChildren<Ranorex.IosElement>();  
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // container0 has 0 children
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Report.Info("EmptyList does not exist within the required time.");
        }
    }
```

This is the report:

```
     11:49.047 Info User
```

DumpProperties. UITableViewWrapperView2 (/mobileapp[@title='com.365agile.enterprise.365Agile-TEST']/form/container[@caption='' and @containertype='LayoutContainer']/container/container/container/container/container/container/table/container[1])
11:50.518 Info User

- Caption =
  11:50.565 Info User
- ContainerType =
  11:50.616 Info User
- AccessibilityHint =
  11:50.667 Info User
- ControlTag = 0
  11:50.733 Info User
- LocalizationKey =
  11:50.800 Info User
- AccessibilityId =
  11:50.888 Info User
- AccessibilityLabel =
  11:50.949 Info User
- PlatformClass = UITableViewWrapperView
  11:51.000 Info User
- TemporaryElementId = 1330140672
  11:51.050 Info User

  Counting forms.
  11:51.100 Info User

  Wait_For_Control: UITableViewWrapperView2
  11:51.218 Success User

  UITableViewWrapperView2 found. Time taken = 67 ms.
  11:51.329 Info User

  Container has 7 children.
  11:51.401 Info User

  Test Form #635845670192988975
  11:51.465 Info User

  Test Form #635845679337106635
  11:51.517 Info User

  Test Form #635845695457811567
  11:51.566 Info User

  Test Form #635845705569626407
  11:51.631 Info User

  Test Form #635845710180283275
  11:51.683 Info User

  Test Form #635845716350372760
  11:51.733 Info User 
  Jump to item
  Test Form #635845755638043639

Comment: why do you need UITableViewWrapperView ? We cannot control it. UIKit elements has so many layers on top of them.We need not know about all of them.

Comment: "why do you need UITableViewWrapperView ?" - because this is the element I can find with the Spy. I have to start somewhere.